# Failed to find geo field [location]

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to call location query on Kibana with index from **Logstash** config

```
mutate {
        add_field => {
                '[locationPoint][lat]' => '%{[document][latitude]}' 
                '[locationPoint][lon]' => '%{[document][longitude]}' 
        }
}
```

What is get from GET myindex:

```
"locationPoint" : {
    "properties" : {
        "lat" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
            }
            }
        },
        "lon" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My *es version*: "7.15.0"

**And i got the error when i try to query items by geo:**

```
"type" : "query_shard_exception",
"reason" : "failed to find geo field [locationPoint]",
```

Comment: It's because `locationPoint` is not of type `geo_point` in your index mapping. Do you mind sharing what you get from `GET myindex`?

Comment: Sorry, i added the response for GET myindex into the Post, could you review it

Comment: Thanks but what you added is the results of `GET myindex/_search` not `GET myindex`

Comment: Thanks @Val, I've just edited the GET myindex response

Comment: Thanks so much!, @Val. I knew what wrong here that I do not run PUT myindex.... to update myindex types. Now it's worked normal.

Comment: Okey @Val, i'll comment the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake here that i need to run

```
PUT myindex
{data types configuration.json}
```

Before run **logstash** to update data